# Django: Create custom template tag -> ImportError

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm sorry to ask this again, but I tried several solutions from stack overflow and some tutorials and I couldn't create a custom template tag yet. All I get is `ImportError: No module named test_tag` when I try to start the server via `python manage.py runserver`.

I created a very basic template tag (found here: [django templatetag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480556/django-templatetag/1480724#1480724)) like so:

My folder structure:

```
demo
    manage.py
    test
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        ...
        templatetags
            __init__.py
            test_tag.py
```

test_tag.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def test_tag(input):
    if "foo" == input:
        return "foo"
    if "bar" == input:
        return "bar"
    if "baz" == input:
        return "baz"
    return ""
```

index.html:

```
{% load test_tag %}
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        {% cms_toolbar %}

        {% foobarbaz "bar" %}
        {% foobarbaz "elephant" %}
        {% foobarbaz "foo" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'test_tag',
    ...
)
```

Please let me know if you need further information from my settings.py and what I did wrong so I can't even start my server. (If I delete 'test_tag' from installed apps I can start the server but I get the error that test_tag is not known, of course).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `templatetags`folder should be within an application.

You project tree should look something like:

```
demo
    manage.py
    test
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
    test_app
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
        templatetags
            __init__.py
            test_tag.py
```

Then, add `test_app` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, and remove `test_tag` from there.

Comment: Now I get `ImportError: No module named test_app`.

Comment: @AlexanderScholz The app should have standard "app structure", see the updated answer.

Comment: Aahh I finally got it :) Thank you so much. I thought "test" is already an app (I'm very new to django). I can omit `models.py`, `views.py`and `tests.py` and it works.

Comment: @AlexanderScholz `test` is a project, not an app ; )

Comment: I have some custom templatetags that are used throughout a project (multiple apps), and those are put into a common directory, e.g. `demo/shared/templatetags`.